# Centralize the words and image of the partition menu?

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

How can I center the words and image of the partition menu?

```
ul # top-menu li {     
  padding-left: 19px; 
  background: url (images / menu-bg.png) no-repeat right 3px; 
}
```

The site is dev.fatorzen.com

Answer (score 1):

The items in the menu, `ul#top-menu li`, have a `padding-left: 19px`. If you remove that the text will be centered.

Comment: I did not understand.

Comment: I think changing your code into `ul#top-menu li { background: url('images/menu-bg.png') no-repeat right; }` would center the text. Perhaps I don't understand your question, in that case I would suggest explaining it a bit more

Comment: The picture menu-bg.png is aligned to the right of the names. Must be centered

Comment: Like `ul#top-menu li { background: url('images/menu-bg.png') no-repeat center; }`?

Comment: Now only the image centered, but the words do not.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul#top-menu li {
/* padding-left: 19px;  Remove this */
background: url(images/menu-bg.png) no-repeat right 3px;
margin: 0 auto; /* added this */
display: inline-block; /* added this */
}

.nav li {
/* float: left; Remove this */
position: relative;
}

ul#top-menu {
float: left;
width: 100%; /* added this */
text-align: center; /* added this */
margin: 0 auto; /* added this */
}
```

You floated elements when you should have used inline-block so that you can center things properly.